# PrintDialog selected papersource

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, printdialog

I'm trying to send multiple documents directly to the printer after selecting print options from the `PrintDialog` class.

I need to retrieve the selected papersource. Unfortunatly, I can only find all papersources from the printer, not the selected one.

Here is a sample of my code (shorten version):

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument document;

//...

PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
pDialog.ShowDialog();

document.PrintOptions.PrinterName = pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;   //OK

//Here I need to set the papersource
//document.PrintOptions.PaperSource = ???

document.printToPrinter(pDialog.PrinterSettings.Copies, false, 0, 0)
```

Am I using the good object to do this?

Note: the `PageSetupDialog` doesn't provide me the printer option since i'm using windows 7.

Comment: PageSetupDialog doesn't provide "the printer option", its Document property does.  Select the printer first, the page setup next.

Comment: The problem is I can select the papersource in the `PrintDialog` window, but I can't get it in the code to send it back to my document.

Comment: You need to assign the PrintDialog.Document property.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention I'm trying to do this for Crystal report (my ReportDocument is `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument`. Editing my question.

Comment: Found my answer, thanks for the comment Hans, it guided me! I'll post it when it'll fully tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question with Hans Passant comment. Thanks to him.

In order to get the `PaperSource` from the `PrintDialog`, I had to set a fake `PrintDocument` to it.

The `PrintDialog` doesn't keep the papersource directly. Instead, it sets the `PrintDialog.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource`.

Here is what it looks like:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument document;

PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
pDialog.Document = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
pDialog.ShowDialog();

document.PrintOptions.PrinterName = pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
document.PrintOptions.CustomPaperSource = pDialog.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource;

document.printToPrinter(pDialog.PrinterSettings.Copies, false, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? Might help finding a "real" solution.